# How to delete a node in HashTable in Java?

Tags: java, hashtable

I'm a newbie in programming. I am currently learning Java Programming Language. My problem is, I am trying to delete a specific node that contains a value in HashTable but I can't figure it out where did I go wrong. Can someone explains to me on how to delete this specific node? Thank you in advance. Sorry for my bad English.

Output that I want to aim: **"Albert"** and **"Timmy"** should be deleted.

This is my code:

Class: **HashEntry**

```
public class HashEntry {
    private int key;
    private String value;
    private HashEntry next;

    public HashEntry() {
        this.next = null;
    }

    public HashEntry(int key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setNext(HashEntry next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public HashEntry getNext() {
        return this.next;
    }
}
```

Class: **HashTableArray**

```
public class HashTableArray {
    HashEntry[] arrayHash;
    int size;

    public HashTableArray(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        arrayHash = new HashEntry[size];
    }

    public int getHash(int key) {
        return key % size;
    } 

    public void insert(int key, String value){
        int hashInd = getHash(key);
        HashEntry newVal = new HashEntry(key, value);
        if (arrayHash[hashInd] == null) {
            arrayHash[hashInd] = newVal;
        }
        else {
            HashEntry arrayValue = arrayHash[hashInd];
            while (arrayValue.getNext() != null) {
                arrayValue = arrayValue.getNext();
            }
            arrayValue.setNext(newVal);
        }
    }

    public void displayTable() {
        System.out.println("Hash Table:");
        for (int i=0; i<arrayHash.length; i++) {
            if(arrayHash[i] != null) {
                HashEntry temp = arrayHash[i];
                while(temp.getNext() != null) {
                    System.out.println(temp.getKey() + ", " + temp.getValue());
                    temp = temp.getNext();
                }
                System.out.println(temp.getKey() + ", " + temp.getValue()); 
            }
        }    
    }
    public void delete (int key, String value) {
        int hashInd = getHash(key);
        HashEntry head = arrayHash[hashInd];
        if (arrayHash[hashInd] != null) {

            HashEntry temp = head, prev = null;
            if (temp.getNext() == null && head.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                head = null;
            }
            else if (temp.getNext() != null && temp.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                head = temp.getNext();
            }
            else {
                while(!temp.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                    prev = temp;
                    temp = temp.getNext();
                }
                if (temp == null) {
                    prev.setNext(null);
                }
                else {
                    prev.setNext(temp.getNext());   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Class: **HashTableProgram**

```
public class HashTableProgram {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashTableArray h = new HashTableArray (10);

        h.insert(12, "Albert");
        h.insert(26, "Johnson");
        h.insert(5, "Timmy");
        h.insert(12, "George");

        h.displayTable();

        h.delete(12, "Albert");
        h.delete(5, "Timmy");

        System.out.println("\nAfter deleted...");
        h.displayTable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick test, the problem lies in your delete method in HashTableArray, you should change

```
head = null;

head = temp.getNext();
```

to

```
arrayHash[hashInd] = null;

arrayHash[hashInd] = temp.getNext();
```

The final code will look like this:

```
public void delete(int key, String value) {
    int hashInd = getHash(key);
    HashEntry head = arrayHash[hashInd];
    if (arrayHash[hashInd] != null) {

        HashEntry temp = head, prev = null;
        if (temp.getNext() == null && head.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
            arrayHash[hashInd] = null;
        } else if (head.getNext() != null && head.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
            arrayHash[hashInd] = temp.getNext();
        } else {
            while (!temp.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp.getNext();
            }
            if (temp == null) {
                prev.setNext(null);
            } else {
                prev.setNext(temp.getNext());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when you assign `arrayHash[hashInd]` to `head` like this:

```
HashEntry head = arrayHash[hashInd];
```

You are creating a reference (or pointer) variable `head` who is pointing to the actual HashEntry data on the heap. If you try to set `head` to **null**, you are just changing what the `head` is pointing to, and now it points to **null**. You are not changing the actual HashEntry data in `arrayHash`.